# Barred Greek letter Upsilon and Z in latex

Tags: equations, amsmath, greek

I need to have a barred Upsilon in math equation (`$\boldsymbol\Upsilon$`) in latex. How can write it? Moreover, I need the barred `$\boldsymbol{Z}$` to use in math equation. Thanks.

Comment: `$\boldsymbol{\Upsilon}$` and `$\boldsymbol{Z}$`?

Comment: Yes, with barred (a stroke through it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mybar}[1]{\setbox0\hbox{$\boldsymbol{#1}$}%
\makebox[\the\wd0][c]{%
\rule[0.42\ht0]{0.75\wd0}{0.7pt}}\hspace*{-\the\wd0}\boldsymbol{#1}}
\begin{document}
$a=\mybar\Upsilon+b+5\mybar{Z}+2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

At the moment, the bar is attached at 42% of the height of the character (`0.42`), it is 75% of the width of the character long (`0.75`) and the line width is `0.7pt`. You can change these parameters to your liking.

You may also want to factor the `\boldsymbol` out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\mybar}[1]{\ifmmode\setbox0\hbox{$#1$}%
\else
\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\fi
\makebox[\the\wd0][c]{%
\rule[0.42\ht0]{0.75\wd0}{0.7pt}}\hspace*{-\the\wd0}#1}
\begin{document}
$a=\mybar{\boldsymbol{\Upsilon}}+b+5\mybar{Z}+2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I also need another character as: a letter like "H" in mathbold but with two hyphen/middle lines equally distant from top and bottom. Would you please let me know about that?

Comment: @Amin Two bars in addition to the one the H already has, or two in total?

Comment: Two in total. But not to be in the middle like H.

Comment: I asked another question. Please see it. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514438/a-letter-like-h-but-with-two-middle-line

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want exactly. I propose this, with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[border = 2pt]{standalone}

 \usepackage{graphicx, stackengine} %
\usepackage{amssymb, rotating, relsize}

\newcommand{\barUpsilon}{\stackMath\mathord{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{-0.45ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$ \relbar $}}{\Upsilon }}}
\newcommand{\barZ}{\stackMath\mathord{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{-0.4ex}{\scalebox{0.67}{$ \relbar $}}{Z}}}

\begin{document}

 $ A\barUpsilon B \barZ $\quad$\mathversion{bold} A\barUpsilon B \barZ $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. However, I need it in boldface. Even I used `\boldsymbol{}` and `\mathbf{}` but none of them worked. Please help me on that.

Comment: Use  `\mathversion{bold}`$ before (in  math mode), or `\boldmath` (before entering math mode).

Comment: Did you load `amsmath` using `boldsymbol`? For me it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Here's a customizable implementation that can also be adapted to other fonts. Some visual experimentation is necessary, because different fonts will have different shapes for the letters. The second argument to `\addbar` specifies a shift factor in units of the symbol's width.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\newcommand{\barredUpsilon}{\addbar{0.05}{}{\Upsilon}}
\newcommand{\barredbUpsilon}{\addbar{0.05}{b}{\bm{\Upsilon}}}
\newcommand{\barredZ}{\addbar{0.07}{}{Z}}
\newcommand{\barredbZ}{\addbar{0.07}{b}{\bm{Z}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addbar}[3]{{\vphantom{#3}\mathpalette\add@bar{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}}
\newcommand{\add@bar}[2]{\add@@bar{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\add@@bar}[4]{%
  % #1 = style selection, #2 = shift factor, #3 = 'b' for bold, #4 = symbol
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1#4$}%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth\kern#2\wd\z@\add@@@bar{#1}{#3}\hidewidth\cr
    \box\z@\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\add@@@bar}[2]{%
  \sbox\tw@{$\m@th#1\newmcodes@\if\relax#2\relax-\else\bm{-}\fi$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr(\ht\z@-\ht\tw@)/2}{\usebox\tw@}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\barredUpsilon+\barredbUpsilon+\barredZ+\barredbZ$

% emulate subscripts
$\scriptstyle\barredUpsilon+\barredbUpsilon+\barredZ+\barredbZ$

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For slashed symbols you can use the `slashed` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}

\begin{document}

$\mathbf{\slashed{\Upsilon}}+\slashed{Z}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. These are also useful. However, what I need to use is a small line/stroke at the middle of these letters.