# A letter like H but with two middle line

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I need another character as: a letter like "H" in `\mathbold` but with two hyphen/middle lines equally distant from top and bottom. Would you please let me know how to write it? Thanks.

Edit:
I used the following code which is genuinely by the great answer of `@Schrödinger's cat`[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514435/120126). It is not perfect for this question, but fine.

```
\newcommand{\barH}{\stackMath\mathord{\stackinset{c}{0ex}{c}{-0.055ex}{\scalebox{0.67}{$ \relbar $}}{\mathbf H}}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want `\mathbb{H}`?

Comment: Yes. I don not want \mathbb{H}.

Comment: do you want it to look like H or more like `$ A \mathrel{{\models}\!{|}} B$` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The thing that I want looks like the one showed by the answer below but has some compilation problem.

Comment: Editing the used solution into your question isn't really a thing on SE. If an answer is what you used, mark it as accepted and you're done. If the answer led you to something similar, you can still accept the answer, and perhaps even add your own answer with what you used exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly modified version of [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514431/barred-greek-letter-upsilon-and-z-in-latex/514435#514435), in which all parameters are stored in keys, allows you to do that: just add two bars on top of two `I`s at different heights. The syntax is now such that you can optionally modify all parameters on the fly, `h` is the relative height, `w` is the fraction of the width, `s` is a shift that can be positive or negative and `line width` is, well, the line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfkeys{/bar/.cd,h/.initial=0.42,w/.initial=0.75,s/.initial=0pt,line width/.initial=0.7pt}
\newcommand{\mybar}[2][]{\pgfkeys{/bar/.cd,#1}%
\ifmmode\setbox0\hbox{$#2$}%
\else
\setbox0\hbox{#1}%
\fi
\makebox[\the\wd0][c]{%
\hspace*{\pgfkeysvalueof{/bar/s}}%
\rule[\pgfkeysvalueof{/bar/h}\ht0]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/bar/w}\wd0}{%
\pgfkeysvalueof{/bar/line width}}}\hspace*{-\the\wd0}#2}
\begin{document}
$a=\mybar{\boldsymbol{\Upsilon}}+b+5\mybar{\boldsymbol{Z}}
+2\mybar[h=0.60,w=0.55,s=0.5pt]{\mybar[h=0.24,w=0.55,s=-0.5pt]{{\boldsymbol{I\hspace*{-1pt}I}}}}
-3H$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But this time it has some compilation problem. It does not proceed. Just shows the rounding cycle shape.

Comment: @Amin I am sorry to hear this. I tested it on two different computers, both of which have TeXLive2019 on it. On both it works fine. What does the log file say?

Comment: It does not say anything. Mine is also TexLive 2019.

Comment: @Amin You did not, by chance, forget `\end{document}`? This gives these symptoms.

Comment: No. Every other thing is fine. As I remove that part it works.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see an example somewhere?

[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) yields nothing (with my drawing skills; maybe you could draw an "official" sketch?).

[Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) finds this:

- http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/294
- http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/10726